# Print the prerequisites to a target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

This is easily a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727059/how-to-print-all-the-prerequisites-and-build-rules-for-a-target-using-make), but it has not been answered, for what I can see.

Here is my goal: to be able to print the prerequisites to a target.

I have some kind of a solution but it feels like a hack to me.

Say the target is `all`, and it only has prerequisites, in a file named `makefile-1`:

```
all: foo

all: bar baz
```

I can use another makefile named `makefile-2`:

```
all:
ifeq ($(SHOW),yes)
    echo $^
else
    cat $^
endif
```

This kind of gives me what I need, when invoked properly:

```
$ make -f makefile-1 -f makefile-2
cat foo bar baz
$ make -s SHOW=yes -f makefile-1 -f makefile-2
foo bar baz
```

But I am not sure what to do if the prerequisite actually has a recipe in the original makefile, or if there is a better/cleaner way.

Comment: You want to be able to, without building the target, get *just* its prerequisites?

Comment: @EtanReisner yes, exactly. I know it's a bit strange. Maybe i need to describe my actual problem in more detail but experience has taught me that easily leads to questions closed because they are "opinion based".

Comment: Do you need to do this *inside* make? Do you need to do this for arbitrary makefiles? Does `make -p` not do what you want (or at least give you the information you want) for some reason? I think you need to be a little more clear about what *exactly* you are trying to do here and what your goal is.

Comment: @EtanReisner I was not thinking clearly. What I probably need is `make -qp | grep '^all:'` to get the line with the target `all` and its prerequisites. The `-p` option was mentioned in the answer to the linked question; should I just delete my question?

Comment: Either that or write that up as an answer (credit the other answer) and accept it probably.

Comment: @EtanReisner I tend to skimp over answers that have no code at all, as the answer to that other question. A bad habit.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An easier way to show the prerequisites to a target without building the target would probably be to use the `-p` option (as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13727059/how-to-print-all-the-prerequisites-and-build-rules-for-a-target-using-make?lq=1)) and `-q` options together, as suggested on the [GNU-Make manual page](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Options-Summary.html#Options-Summary) (long name for the option is `--print-data-base`):

```
make -qp | grep '^all:'
```

This will print the database and select only the line which has the target `all` and its prerequisites. If there is a rule for that target, it would be at the end of the same paragraph (if I am understanding the format of the output correctly).

If multiple makefiles are used, one can specify all of them with the `-f` option:

```
make -f makefile-1 -f makefile-2 -qp
```

This will of course collect prerequisites for the same target from all makefiles, but the target cannot have a rule specified in more than one file.